# Getting Error In installing Nuget Package Microsoft.UI.Xaml in window 10 ver 1903 and visual studio 2019

Tags: wpf, windows, visual-studio, xaml, nuget-package

I want to work xaml Islands in a WPF project and need to install Microsoft.UI.Xaml. My windows version is 1903 and am using visual studio 2019.
But I get the error :

```
   Microsoft.UI.Xaml nuget package requires TargetPlatformVersion >= 10.0.18362.0 (current project is -1)
```

Comment: Have a look at MSDN [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/xaml-islands) You should modify your project to support Windows Runtime APIs

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Thank you. I've read this article and added app.manifest as it says. but still getting the error.